# OleDB Exception thrown with OleDbDataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(OLEDBhelper.ConnectionString);
String SqlStt = "SELECT * FROM Groups where CodeTribe=@Code";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SqlStt, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", p);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter Data = new OleDbDataAdapter(command.CommandText, conn);
conn.Close();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

Data.Fill(ds);
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     DataGridViewRow NewRow = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridViewGroups.Rows[0].Clone();
     NewRow.Cells[0].Value = row["CodeGroup"].ToString();
     NewRow.Cells[1].Value = row["NameGroup"].ToString();
     dataGridViewGroups.Rows.Add(NewRow);
}
```

p is a number

The connection is fine, I get an OleDB exeption at

```
Data.Fill(ds);
```

I think that something is wrong with my query but I dont know where

Comment: What is the exception exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül, the first of the overloads takes `DataSet` only?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `.Close();`

```
OleDbDataAdapter Data = new OleDbDataAdapter(command.CommandText, conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

Data.Fill(ds);
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     DataGridViewRow NewRow = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridViewGroups.Rows[0].Clone();
     NewRow.Cells[0].Value = row["CodeGroup"].ToString();
     NewRow.Cells[1].Value = row["NameGroup"].ToString();
     dataGridViewGroups.Rows.Add(NewRow);
}

conn.Close();//You might be able to add this under the Data.Fill()
```

Comment: Are you sure `Fill` method requires open connection?

Comment: I think it does? If you explicitly call open, hen you also have to call close - it's been a while since I've used DataSets.